# remove quotes with preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex

When I try  to remove quotes from :
`"ABC"->ABC` and `'ABC'->ABC`
I get the following result:

```
&#34;ABC&#34;
```

This is the code I have:

```
$company=filter_var( $_POST['company'],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if ((!empty($company)) && (preg_match('/[a-z0-9\s\"\'\&]/i',$company))
   && (strlen($company) <= 30)){
    $company=preg_replace('/[\'\"]/','', $company);
    }
```

Comment: How do you _get result_? As tested `var_dump()` dumps correct value.

Comment: Looks like you have entities, not quotes. Maybe `(&#34;|\'|"|&#39;)` but thats just a start, why do you need to remove quotes, hopefully not a SQL fix attempt

Answer (score 1):

Well you are filtering with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`, which encodes `"` as `&#34;` and `'` as `&#39;`.  From the manual [Sanitize Filters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php):

> Strip tags and **HTML-encode double and single quotes**, optionally strip or encode special characters. Encoding quotes can be disabled by setting **FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES**.

So if you really need that filter, then don't encode quotes:

```
$company = filter_var($_POST['company'],
                      FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `preg_replace`, You could also remove not only quotes(`'` or `"`) but also entities(`&#39;` or `&#34;`).

```php
$company = "remove ' or &#39; and \" or &#34;";
echo $company.'<br>'; //Prints: remove ' or ' and " or "
$company = preg_replace('/[&#39;|\'|\"|&#34;]*/', '', $company);
echo $company.'<br>'; //Prints: remove or and or
```

Answer (score -1):

for python:

```py
import re

word = 'hello \'sigle quote\' and "double quote"';
word = re.sub(r"('|\")", "", word)
```

this regex matches one single or one double quote and replaces it with empty string.

adapt it to your own code and use. good luck

more info about the regex alternation operator here in the link: https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

edit:

for php:

```php
$word = 'hello \'sigle quote\' and "double quote"';
$word = preg_replace('/(\'|")/', '', $word);
```

Comment: sorry my friend,  I've edited my answer ))